# air conditioner outlet

Tags: electrical

I was given an ac unit.  got it home and realize plug was different.  There's no identifying info on or with unit but googling plug it appears it may be 20 amp.
The outlet where I was going too plug ac into is on a 20 amp run back too panel with a gfi at outlet.  can I just remove gfi, and instal a 20 amp outlet top match my plug?

Comment: Can you post photos of the plug and receptacle?

Comment: Also can you verify the size of the wire back to the panel, is it 12 or 14 gauge?

Comment: This may be doable but we really need to see that plug. It can be one of two things.   Also, there may be a reason you "were given" it -- how many hours do you plan to run it per year?